# Lookup disk device elements in libvirt xml with Ansible

Tags: xml, ansible, libvirt

I'm trying to get list of attached disks from libvirt domain XML to find combinations of source and target device currently present.

XML:

```
<domain type='kvm' id='1'>
  <name>vm1</name>
  ...
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type='block' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='native' discard='unmap'/>
      <source dev='/dev/data/vm-vm1' index='2'/>
      <backingStore/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <alias name='virtio-disk0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x04' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    ...
  </devices>
</domain>
```

Here is attempt using xml module (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/xml_module.html)
But my xpath is currently just resulting in one big list of dictionaries with attributes of all block devices.

```
- command: /usr/bin/virsh dumpxml {{ item.name }}
  register: domxml
  with_items: "{{ vms }}"
  when: item.host == inventory_hostname

- xml:
    xmlstring: "{{ item.stdout }}"
    content: attribute
    xpath: /domain/devices/disk[@type='block']/*
  register: vm_mounts_xml
  with_items: "{{ domxml.results }}"

- set_fact:
    vm_mounts_current: "{{ vm_mounts_current | default([]) + [{'vm': item.0.item.item.name, 'source': item.1.source.dev, 'target': item.1.target.dev}] }}"
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ vm_mounts_xml.results }}"
    - matches
```

**edit:**
Based on [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72405844/19213117) from [larsks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147356/larsks), I ended up using existing filter plugin `from_xml` which also does dictionary from xml.

Tasks:

```
- set_fact:
    dom_dict: "{{ item.stdout|ansible.utils.from_xml }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ dom_xml.results }}"

- set_fact:
    vm_mounts_current: "{{ vm_mounts_current | default([]) + [{'vm': item.0.name, 'source': item.1.source['@dev'], 'target': item.1.target['@dev']}] }}"
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ dom_dict }}"
    - devices.disk
  when: item.1.source['@dev'] is defined
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that avoids the problems with the previous answer. This requires the use of some custom filters to make it easier working with the XML.

First, we create a `filter_plugins` directory next to our playbook,
and create `filter_plugins/xmlutils.py` with the following content:

```
import lxml.etree
import xmltodict


def xpath_filter(v, expr):
    tree = lxml.etree.fromstring(v)
    res = tree.xpath(expr)
    return res


def xmltostring_filter(v):
    return lxml.etree.tostring(v)


def xmltodict_filter(v):
    return xmltodict.parse(v)


class FilterModule:
    def filters(self):
        return {
            "xpath": xpath_filter,
            "xmltostring": xmltostring_filter,
            "xmltodict": xmltodict_filter,
        }
```

Note that this requires both the `lxml` and the `xmltodict` modules,
so you'll need to `pip install lxml xmltodict`.

With these filters, we can write a playbook like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    domxml:
      results:
        - item:
            name: vm1
          stdout: |
            <domain type='kvm' id='1'>
              <name>vm1</name>
              <devices>
                <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
                <disk type='block' device='disk'>
                  <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='native' discard='unmap'/>
                  <source dev='/dev/data/vm-vm1' index='1'/>
                  <backingStore/>
                  <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
                  <alias name='virtio-disk0'/>
                  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x04' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
                </disk>
                <disk type='block' device='disk'>
                  <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='native' discard='unmap'/>
                  <source dev='/dev/data/vm-vm1-b' index='2'/>
                  <backingStore/>
                  <target dev='vdb' bus='virtio'/>
                  <alias name='virtio-disk0'/>
                  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x04' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
                </disk>
              </devices>
            </domain>
        - item:
            name: vm2
          stdout: |
            <domain type='kvm' id='2'>
              <name>vm2</name>
              <devices>
                <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
                <disk type='block' device='disk'>
                  <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='native' discard='unmap'/>
                  <source dev='/dev/data/vm-vm2' index='2'/>
                  <backingStore/>
                  <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
                  <alias name='virtio-disk0'/>
                  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x04' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
                </disk>
              </devices>
            </domain>

  tasks:

    # This task builds a variable name `vm_disks` that is
    # a list of dictionaries of the form:
    #
    # {
    #   "name": "vm name",
    #   "disks: [ ...list of disk... ]
    # }
    #
    # This structure allows us to use this list with the `subelements`
    # filter in a subsequent task.
    #
    - set_fact:
        vm_disks: >-
          {{
            vm_disks + [{
              'name': item.item.name,
              'disks': item.stdout|xpath('/domain/devices/disk')|map('xmltostring')|map('xmltodict')
            }]
          }}
      vars:
        vm_disks: []
      loop: "{{ domxml.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item.name }}"

    - debug:
        msg:
          - "vm: {{ item.0.name }}"
          - "source: {{ item.1.disk.source['@dev'] }}"
          - "target: {{ item.1.disk.target['@dev'] }}"
      loop: "{{ vm_disks|subelements('disks') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.name }}:{{ item.1.disk.target['@dev'] }}"
```

By using `xmltodict` to transform the `<disk>` elements into a Python dictionary, we end up with something that is much easier to manipulate in Ansible.

The result of the `set_fact` task (given the example input) is a
structure that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "vm1",
        "disks": [
            {
                "disk": {
                    ...
                    "source": {
                        "@dev": "/dev/data/vm-vm1",
                        "@index": "1"
                    },
                    "target": {
                        "@bus": "virtio",
                        "@dev": "vda"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "disk": {
                    ...
                    "source": {
                        "@dev": "/dev/data/vm-vm1-b",
                        "@index": "2"
                    },
                    "target": {
                        "@bus": "virtio",
                        "@dev": "vdb"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "vm2",
        "disks": [
            {
                "disk": {
                    ...
                    "source": {
                        "@dev": "/dev/data/vm-vm2",
                        "@index": "2"
                    },
                    "target": {
                        "@bus": "virtio",
                        "@dev": "vda"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

That already has the information you want. The `debug` task produces
this output:

```
TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=vm1:vda) => {
    "msg": [
        "vm: vm1",
        "source: /dev/data/vm-vm1",
        "target: vda"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=vm1:vdb) => {
    "msg": [
        "vm: vm1",
        "source: /dev/data/vm-vm1-b",
        "target: vdb"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=vm2:vda) => {
    "msg": [
        "vm: vm2",
        "source: /dev/data/vm-vm2",
        "target: vda"
    ]
}
```

If you prefer a slightly different structure, we can write another
`set_fact` task like this:

```
    - set_fact:
        vm_mounts: >-
          {{
            vm_mounts|combine({item.0.name: [{
              'source': item.1.disk.source['@dev'],
              'target': item.1.disk.target['@dev'],
            }]}, list_merge='append')
          }}
      vars:
        vm_mounts: {}
      loop: "{{ vm_disks|subelements('disks') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.name }}:{{ item.1.disk.target['@dev'] }}"
```

That will produce a variable `vm_mounts` that looks like:

```
TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "vm_mounts": {
        "vm1": [
            {
                "source": "/dev/data/vm-vm1",
                "target": "vda"
            },
            {
                "source": "/dev/data/vm-vm1-b",
                "target": "vdb"
            }
        ],
        "vm2": [
            {
                "source": "/dev/data/vm-vm2",
                "target": "vda"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

You can find a complete runnable example [here](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-72403652).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are right it works part of the way, but all the devices attributes are unstructured in the matches from XML, meaning you can't tell that source and target belongs to the same disk.

And yes I did also have a `when` condition to only run set_fact for items where the desired fields is defined.

Comment: I've updated this answer with an alternative solution: a couple of prerequisites, but it gets you what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I ended up using existing filter plugin from_xml which also does dictionary from xml. Put as an edit in question.